# How to convert vc++(ex: IListPtr ) pointer to std::list?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, com

Can any body help me in converting Interface Pointer to list variable in vc++ since i am getting the error while typeconversion

> error 2440 "type cast" :cannot convert from '_bstr_t' to 'std::list<_Ty>'

Edit: I have done it like this:

**C#**

```
List<string> Disp() {
    List<string> li = new List<string>();
    li.Add("Ravi");
    li.Add("Raj");
    Return li;
}
```

**C++**

```
void main() {
    HRESULT Hr=CoInitilize(NULL);
    ITestPtr p(__uuid("DemoClass");
    std::list l=(std::list)p->Disp();
}
```

But strangely some times it shows that Disp is not a member of ITest and sometimes that type conversion error. I have verified this is only because of when the return type is List

Comment: First, you need to show us some code. Second, we look at your code and give you advice. Nifty, huh?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [Boost Range MFC/ATL Extenstion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/range/doc/mfc_atl.html)

```
CList<CString> vcList;
std::list<T> stdList;
BOOST_FOREACH( CString s, vcList)
{
    stdList.push_back(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the best thing to do unless there's a Really Nice Shortcut is manually walk the CLI list and push_back() onto the std::list.

As a possible example of what it might look like(I don't know C++/CLI)

```
std::list<T> stdlist;
foreach(T t in CLIlist)
{
    stdlist.push_back(t);
}
```